# CSS, dropdown menu: ul sub-menu between li's

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm building a three-level dropdown menu and I have a problem with the styling.

I have this kind of thing:

[image]

There is a li (Corsi) that contains a ul (First menu) that contains three li's. 
Something like this:

```
<ul><li>Corsi
    <ul><li>First menu
        <ul><li>Sub menu 1</li>
        <li>Sub menu 2</li>
        <li>Sub menu 3</li></ul>
    </li></ul>
</li></ul>
```

Now, I want to add another element to the second ul, and I want it to go below the submenu. But I can't, because the new li overlays the first element of the submenu (see code and image below).

```
<ul><li>Corsi
    <ul><li>First menu
        <ul><li>Sub menu 1</li>
        <li>Sub menu 2</li>
        <li>Sub menu 3</li></ul>
    </li>
    <li>New li</li></ul>
</li></ul>
```

[image]

And here's the CSS code:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
}

ul a {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width: 19%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 17px;
    padding: 20px 0 6%;
}

ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    top: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

ul ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

ul ul a {
    padding: 20px 47px;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

ul > ul > a {
    width: 100%;
}

ul ul ul {
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

What can I do to make the second li go below the submenu?

Thank you all and sorry if my explanation wasn't the best.

Comment: Well without seeing your CSS it's kind of impossible to point out what you might be doing wrong. Make a fiddle with how you have it now.

Comment: please reproduce the issue in a fiddle..

Comment: @SeanStopnik you are totally right.

Comment: 1) Your CSS posted here doesn't match your screenshots at all. 2) Everything floats, even the absolutely positioned elements, that can't be right. And none of the floats gets cleared.